# How to call constructor function when using ESM import syntax in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, import, es6-modules

in NodeJS you can 'import' an external file like so:

```js
var myModule = require('./module.js');
```

[ESM module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements)s allow you to do the same in nodejs as you do in the backend...

```js
import myModule from './module.js';
```

However, with the require syntax, I can call a constructor function (forgive if my term is wrong) like so:

```js
var myModule = require('./module.js')(myObject);
```

... how would one do this with ESM syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this is possible, I think you just have to use

```js
import MyModule from './module';
const myModule = MyModule();
```

For this reason I use `PascalCase` for modules, even though that's not the normal convention.